# Current consumption of PWM controlled MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, current, fet

I'm trying to design an application in which a DC/DC converter with limited output current capabilities drives the gate of one or more transistors in PWM mode. My question is, how can I estimate the average current consumption of the switching process itself (not that of the controlled current) if I know the switching frequency, the gate on voltage as well as all the common parameters given in a transistor datasheet?

Can I calculate this current via Switching Energy * frequency / Von?

And can I design the DC/DC converter with this current in mind or do I have to consider other factors as well, e.g. that the switching current isn't steady but instead consists of lots of peaks which have higher amplitudes than the average current value? Do typcial DC/DC converters like buck / boost provide those spike currents even if they exceed their max currents as long as they are short enough?

Concrete case which inspired my question was the control of a BLDC motor with 3 half bridges. There I needed a DC/DC for the gate voltage and my question was what max current should I choose for that DC/DC? Does switching current event matter at all? Do the high amp spikes of MOSFET switching matter or only their average due to the huge output capacitors in DC/DC converters?

Know that there are a lot of questions, don't mind to search intensively / open another question about that DC/DC converter spike current behaviour part if you think it's wiser. Couldn't find a question about switching current consumption though.

Hope to get help!

Comment: Why a DC/DC converter? Why not a regular MOSFET driver? What are the voltages that you're working with?

Comment: Driving a (power) MOSFET is similar to charging/discharging a capacitor. Unless you switch on/off with a high frequency (my guess: above 100 kHz) and/or many MOSFETs simultaneously you will not need much current. For efficiency, charging the gate should be fast, the current should come from a large capacitor on the supply, not the supply itself. Few regulators (switching or linear) are fast enough anyway. More theory is discussed in books about DCDC (switching) converters as switching losses (due to gate charging/discharging) are also a concern there.

Comment: In the BLDC case mentioned above the only available source were two LiPo batteries wired in serial, resulting in appr. 30 V. But as our halfbridge MOSFET's only accepted 20 V gate voltage at max and unbalancing one LiPo battery to use it's 15 V separately was to risky we decided for a DC/DC for the 15 V gate supply.

Comment: Too many questions means opinions for answers. VTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to design an application in which a DC/DC converter with
>   limited output current capabilities drives the gate of one or more
>   transistors in PWM mode

There may be some confusion here. You drive the gate of a MOSFET typically with a pulses of varying mark-space ratio. That is a standard way of achieving PWM control. Whether ultimately the pulses are derived from a DC to DC converter is a detail that is largely irrelevant to working out how much power is wasted driving the MOSFET gate.

The gate-source loss comes about because you charge a capacitor to some voltage then you discharge it.

To calculate that loss, use the energy equation for a capacitor, work = \$CV^2/2\$. So, if the capacitance is (say) 5 nF and you charge it to 10 volts, then you are putting in an energy of 250 nJ. When you discharge it that energy is lost forever so, if that happens at a switching (PWM) frequency of 100 kHz, the power lost in driving the gate is 25 mW.

If you have 6 similar MOSFETs in your motor controller then the total power wasted in driving them at 100 kHz is 150 mW.

Regards the maximum current injected into the gate to raise it to 10 volts, you use the formula I = C dv/dt where dv/dt is 10 volts divided by the rise time of the gate drive. If you want very fast switching (not always desireable) than you need more current.

For the example of 100 kHz PWM, the switching period is 10 us and if you said that no more than 5% of the time was spent charging up the gate then dt = 500 ns.

I = 5 nF * 10V/500 ns = 100 mA.

If you wanted the switching 5 times faster then current would need to be 500 mA.